# Error executing request using httpService with typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am using `nestjs` to build an application. I'm trying to use `httpService` to make a request to the server and get an admin token.

I am getting an error. I don't know the reason or what the error represents. Can someone help me?

My request code is this:

[image]

Below is the return value from server:

[image]

Comment: Does the URL you are trying to hit accept JSON? A 415 means you're sending an unsupported media type

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` to indicate that you're sending a JSON payload.

You can do that by passing an [AxiosRequestConfig](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) as the third argument to `this.httpService.post()`:

```json
{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}
```